# mod_rewrite RewriteRule In Same Directory With .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around how I should get this accomplished. Everything I'm attempting turns out to cause an infinite redirect loop.

Here is the scenario. A site is currently being worked on at `http://example.com`. While this site is being worked on, I want to send all visitors to, let's say `http://example.com/temp.html`. I'm basically wanting a catch-all so that for any URL a person might type/click (`http://example.com/blog/post-1`) they get redirected to the root HTML directory, but only to that `temp.html` page. Normally this is a straight forward process, but the problem I'm running into is the fact that I want visitors who visit any part of the domain (which includes the root directory) will be directed to the root directory, although to a specific page. But it's because of this that my code keeps causing a redirect loop.

So my first question is of course, what am I missing? How can I accomplish this? My second question would be, is this the best method for dealing with sites that are temporarily being worked on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a .htaccess file in your root directory with the following content :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /paht/to/temp.html
```

This will display the temp.html every time the side is requested.
And it doesn't matter which url is entered (http://example.com/blog/post-1 or http://example.com/blog/randomURL)

Comment: Well that worked like a charm and you helped me figure out why mine wasn't working. Where you specified the path, I was specifying the full domain path, which I believe was what caused the infinite loop. However just using ``/path/to/temp`` worked fine. Now on to play with some more RewriteCond :)